# XSL lookup from a properties (csv) file

Tags: xslt, lookup

I have an XML which needs to be formatted to a CSV. I have chosen XSL to do achieve this. In addition to the XML file, I have a Properties file which needs to be looked through for getting the values for the variables defined in the XML. 
Can any one help me in how to do the lookups via an XSL using an external csv file?

**CSV file after transformation:**
Article.AclFlag|%field.Article.AclFlag.name|false|true|true|||||||||||master-data|%category.MasterData|Integer||0|||Enum.Acls|%enum.Acls.name|%enum.Acls.entry.0;%enum.Acls.entry.1;%enum.Acls.entry.2;%enum.Acls.entry.3;%enum.Acls.entry.4;%enum.Acls.entry.5;%enum.Acls.entry.6;|0;1;2;3;4;5;6;|0;1;2;3;4;5;6;|Article|%entity.Article.name|Product2G Variant

**XSL**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
version="1.0">

<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:output method="text" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="no"/>

<xsl:key name="kEntity" match="entity-type" use="@identifier" />
<xsl:key name="kCategory" match="category" use="@identifier" />
<xsl:key name="kFieldID" match="field-type" use="@identifier" />
<xsl:key name="kEnumID" match="enum" use="@identifier" />
<xsl:key name="k1" match="entry" use="@key"/>

<xsl:variable name="map-doc" select="document('../transform/Properties.properties')"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="repository/custom/entity/field"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="field">
    <xsl:copy>
        <field>
        <xsl:value-of select="@identifier"/>
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="editable"/>
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="visible"/>
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="visible-from-top"/>
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="max-length"/>
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="exportPurpose"/>
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="importPurpose"/>
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="upper-bound"/>
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="average-length"/>
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="active"/>
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="multiline"/>
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="display-by-default"/>
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="richtext"/>
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="value"/>
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        </field>
        <category-ref-name>
            <xsl:value-of select="key('kCategory', @category-ref)/@identifier"/>
            <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="key('kCategory', @category-ref)/name"/>
            <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        </category-ref-name>
        <field-type-ref>
            <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(key('kFieldID', @field-type-ref)/persistence-class-name, 'java.lang.')"/>
            <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        </field-type-ref>
        <proxy-entity-ref>
            <xsl:value-of select="key('kFieldID', @field-type-ref)/@proxy-ref"/>
            <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="key('kFieldID', @field-type-ref)/lower-bound"/>
            <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="key('kFieldID', @field-type-ref)/range-min"/>
            <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="key('kFieldID', @field-type-ref)/range-max"/>
            <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        </proxy-entity-ref>
        <enum-ref-name>
            <xsl:value-of select="key('kEnumID', @enum-ref)/@identifier"/>
            <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="key('kEnumID', @enum-ref)/name"/>
            <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
             <xsl:for-each select="key('kEnumID', @enum-ref)/entry">
                    <xsl:value-of select="@label"/>
                    <xsl:text>;</xsl:text>
            </xsl:for-each>
            <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
             <xsl:for-each select="key('kEnumID', @enum-ref)/entry">
                    <xsl:value-of select="@external-code"/>
                    <xsl:text>;</xsl:text>
            </xsl:for-each>
            <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
             <xsl:for-each select="key('kEnumID', @enum-ref)/entry">
                    <xsl:value-of select="@key"/>
                    <xsl:text>;</xsl:text>
            </xsl:for-each>
            <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>


        </enum-ref-name>
        <entity>
            <xsl:value-of select="../@identifier"/>
            <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="../name"/>
            <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="../@parentEntities-ref"/>

        </entity>
    </xsl:copy>
    <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>
 </xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Properties**

field.Article.AclFlag.name= Object right type

category.MasterData= Header data

enum.Acls.name=Object right types

The csv file is also not formatted well.

**Sample XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<repository>
<types>
<entity-type identifier="ArticleType" identifying-field-type-ref="ArticleType.Id">
  <object-name>article</object-name>
  <class-name>ArticleType</class-name>
  <persistence-xpath>/Article</persistence-xpath>
  <persistence-class-name>db.model.Article</persistence-class-name>
  <lower-bound>1</lower-bound>
  <upper-bound>1</upper-bound>
  <field-type identifier="ArticleType.AclFlag">
    <object-name>aclFlag</object-name>
    <class-name>commons.AclFlags</class-name>
    <persistence-xpath>/aclFlag</persistence-xpath>
    <persistence-class-name>java.lang.Integer</persistence-class-name>
    <fragment-column-access>Article.AclFlag</fragment-column-access>
    <internal>true</internal>
    <lower-bound>0</lower-bound>
    <range-min></range-min>
    <range-max></range-max>
    <min-length>0</min-length>
  </field-type>
  </entity-type>
</types>
<custom>
<category identifier="master-data" order="1">
  <name>%category.MasterData</name>
 </category>
 <enum identifier="Enum.Acls">
  <name>%enum.Acls.name</name>
  <description>%enum.Acls.description</description>
  <class-name>com.heiler.ppm.repository.enumerations.StdEnumProvider</class-name>
  <key-class-name>commons.AclFlags</key-class-name>
  <entry label="%enum.Acls.entry.0" external-code="0" key="0"/>
  <entry label="%enum.Acls.entry.1" external-code="1" key="1"/>
  <entry label="%enum.Acls.entry.2" external-code="2" key="2"/>
  <entry label="%enum.Acls.entry.3" external-code="3" key="3"/>
  <entry label="%enum.Acls.entry.4" external-code="4" key="4"/>
  <entry label="%enum.Acls.entry.5" external-code="5" key="5"/>
  <entry label="%enum.Acls.entry.6" external-code="6" key="6"/>
 </enum>
 <entity entity-type-ref="ArticleType" identifier="Article" parentEntities-ref="Product2G Variant">
  <name>%entity.Article.name</name>
  <description>%entity.Article.description</description>
  <label-pattern-short>{Article.SupplierAID}</label-pattern-short>
  <label-pattern-long>{Article.SupplierAID} - {ArticleLang.DescriptionShort}</label-pattern-long>
   <label-pattern-description>{ArticleLang.DescriptionLong}</label-pattern-description>
   <field identifier="Article.AclFlag" category-ref="master-data" enum-ref="Enum.Acls" field-type-ref="ArticleType.AclFlag">
    <name>%field.Article.AclFlag.name</name>
    <description>%field.Article.AclFlag.description</description>
    <editable>false</editable>
    <visible>true</visible>
    <visible-from-top>true</visible-from-top>
    <help-context></help-context>
    <mergeable>false</mergeable>
    </field>
   </custom>
  </repository>
```

**Sample Properties in XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE properties SYSTEM "http://java.sun.com/dtd/properties.dtd">
<properties>
<comment>Default</comment>
<entry key="field.Article.AclFlag.name">Object right type</entry>
<entry key="category.MasterData">Header data</entry>
<entry key="enum.Acls.name">Object right types</entry>
</properties>
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: It would be much easier if your external "properties" file was XML, rather than CSV. Do you have any control over this? Note that, to help answer your question, it would really help if you showed a sample of your input XML too. Thanks

Comment: Thanks Tim for your response. Added the sample XML as needed.

Comment: @TimC, Not sure, if you have had a chance to look into this.. let me know, if the xml is not accessible or something else here.. Thanks

Comment: You didn't respond to the comment about whether you had any control over the properties file, as it would be easier if it were XML. If you can't change the properties file, you would have to use XSLT 2.0. Can you also confirm what version of XSLT you can use? Thanks

Comment: No, I do not have control over the properties file unfortunately. I would even go for XSLT 2.0 if that would be compatible with CSV and would help me in achieving the results as expected. Thanks

Comment: @TimC, I have checked for the control part on the properties file with the concerned people and they could also provide the file in an XML. Would that be any good you think?

Comment: Yes. That would be much better, as you could use the `document` function to access it. And in XSLT 2.0, you can pass in the document context as the third parameter the `key` function, which makes looking up items from an external XML very easy.

Comment: Copied the sample xml here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that your properties are of this form

```
<entry key="field.Article.AclFlag.name">Object right type</entry>
```

You can define a key to look up `entry` elements by their `key` attribute, and I see such a key already exists in your XSLT

```
<xsl:key name="k1" match="entry" use="@key"/>
```

Next, ensure you have a variable reference to your external XML document

```
<xsl:variable name="map-doc" select="document('../transform/Properties.properties.xml')"/>
```

Then, to look up a value from the properties you can do this (obviously replacing the second argument with the actual value you want to look up):

```
<xsl:variable name="test" select="'enum.Acls.name'" />
<xsl:value-of select="key('k1', $test, $map-doc)" />
```

Note this form of the `key` function, with a third parameter, is only valid in XSLT 2.0. If you were to do `<xsl:value-of select="key('k1', $test) />`, it would look for the value in the input XML, not your properties XML.

In XSLT 1.0 you could do this to change the document context for the key

```
<xsl:variable name="test" select="'enum.Acls.name'" />
<xsl:for-each select="$map-doc">
    <xsl:value-of select="key('k1', $test)" />
</xsl:for-each>
```

Alternatively, do it without a key

```
<xsl:variable name="test" select="'enum.Acls.name'" />
<xsl:value-of select="$map-doc//entry[@key=$test]" />
```

Comment: Thank you very much Tim.  This worked perfect for my requirement.  Appreciate your time and your help.

Comment: I see an interesting behaviour after applying the mapdoc here.

Comment: ,I am loosing the internal references eg: %enum.Acls.entry.4 **Before:** `code` Article.AclFlag|%field.Article.AclFlag.name|false|true|true|||||||||||master-data|%category.MasterData|Integer||0|||Enum.Acls|%enum.Acls.name|%enum.Acls.entry.0;%enum.Acls.entry.1;%enum.Acls.entry.2;%enum.Acls.entry.3;%enum.Acls.entry.4;%enum.Acls.entry.5;%enum.Acls.entry.6;|0;1;2;3;4;5;6;|0;1;2;3;4;5;6;|Article|%entity.Article.name|Product2G 
Variant `code`        **After:**  `code` Article.AclFlag|Object right type|false|true|true|||||||||||||||||||||||Article|%entity.Article.name|Product2G Variant `code`

Comment: You might need to ask a new question about this. It will be hard to diagnose the issue in comments without seeing your latest XSLT. Thanks

Comment: Sure. Have a new created a new quesiton on this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50678046/xsl-lookup-breaking-the-internal-references. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.